# Add columns to a table managed by Sequel Model

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sequel

I'm using Sequel::Model. My model has a set_schema block and a create_table call, so the database is completely managed by the model. The database is sqlite.

I'm trying to add columns to the database and I can't find a way to. Adding fields to the schema has no effect. Adding a migration or an alter_table call doesn't do anything. I've asked on IRC and read the docs. I can't find an example of anyone doing this, but it seems simple.

How do I add a column/field to a Sequel Model?

Comment: You want to do this in runtime? My recommendation for all these types of of questions is create another table we'll call it `attributes` and another table `attribute_values` then the model can have many `attribute_values` which is simply a join of your model.id, attribute.id and then a given value for that attribute. This is extremely flexible and does not require schema change during runtime

Answer (score 0):

I did a bunch of research and talked to Jeremy Evans. I was going about this wrong. The right way to do this was to remove my schema plugin code and create_table block and move to using migrations. The steps I went through were:

1. Remove the schema code (create_table, set_schema) from my modesl
2. Dump the schema from my current sqlite data files into initial migrations into migration files via the sequel -d command
3. Create a new migration that adds the columns I need via add_column calls in an alter_table block in a change block
4. Apply the migrations via the sequel -m command
5. Create rake tasks to run the migrations and hook those tasks into my deploy tasks